# Balloon ToolTip when clicking a button ?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

Instead of sending a MessageBox to the user I would like to send a smaill balloon window next to the clicked button with some texts on it, similar to the taskbar notify balloon tooltip.

How could I make this sort of balloon for the windowsform when the button is clicked ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With following controls on your form,

```
Button button1;
ToolTip toolTip1;
```

You can use this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(sender as Control, "Some text in balloon!");
}
```

Set `toolTip1.IsBalloon = true`

Comment: @decyclone your solution looks really nice and simple but as @Heank Holterman said it will still be shown everytime you hover over the button and I would like for it to show just 1 time when you click the button.

Comment: +1 for posting code that make sense.  I'll avoid mentioning ToolTip.Show()

Comment: @Hans the effect is the same the baloon will show up whenever you hover the button. but thanks.

Comment: @Prix: @Hans is right. To make it come up just once, use `ToolTip.Show()`. Thanks @Henk & @Hans.

Comment: @decyclone it has the same effect as using settooltip I have tried both.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ballontooltip.aspx

Or this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/balloontipsarticle.aspx

Comment: I checked it oout and it looks rather complicated I was looking for something more built-in like the decyclone examples.